# sed regular expression to align function prototypes written across many lines

Tags: regex, sed

OpenGL header gl.h as well as many other headers contains function definitions spread over many lines. Here is an example :

```
GLAPI void glCopyTexSubImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level,
                                GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset,
                                GLint x, GLint y,
                                GLsizei width, GLsizei height );
```

I would like to come up with a regular expression that I could use with sed to align them. The previous example would then become:

```
GLAPI void glCopyTexSubImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level,GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLint x, GLint y,GLsizei width, GLsizei height );
```

The `GLAPI` token is specific to OpenGL, so I’d rather ignore it so that the solution could be used in more contexts.

Comment: You'd better use a code reformat tool for that.

Comment: I just looked up Astyle, but it cannot do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Simple `sed` one-liner will work for you -

```
sed ':a;{N;s/\n */ /};ba' INPUT_FILE
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp
GLAPI void glCopyTexSubImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level,
                                GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset,
                                GLint x, GLint y,
                                GLsizei width, GLsizei height );

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed ':a;{N;s/\n */ /};ba' temp
GLAPI void glCopyTexSubImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ex`:

```
$ echo -e 'g/([^;]*$/,/);$/j\n%p' | ex gl.h
```

- **`/([^;]*$/`** match start
- **`/);$/`** match end

If you want to edit-in-place, change `%p` to `w`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/.*( .*/,/.* );$/{H;//{x;s/\n  */ /gp};d}' file
```